# Are there any cheats in single-player MGS V allowing you to unlock weapons or level up your Mother Base teams?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain, cheats

Basically, I've finished the game, done all the missions (some of them 2 or 3 times), the side ops, and almost all of the replay missions that pop up later on. Even so, I'm only at R&D level 45, still really far away from meeting the R&D team requirements for a lot of weapons and items (level 60 being the highest, I think). I'd like to play around with those items, but I'm not going to just grind the missions over and over (and over) to get them. I'm not interested in playing online, so an offline-only solution or a save-game file would be fine. It seems as if the R&D requirements are calibrated for a longer game, which MGS V is rumored to have been before it was rushed out the door by Konami. So is there a file I can edit or something to either just unlock those weapons and items immediately, or a way to edit my R&D team level?

Comment: Aren't these also used online?  If so, I doubt there would be cheat codes for it.

Comment: @Powerlord I suppose you're right, I've never played it online. I'll edit the question.

Comment: "It seems as if the R&D requirements are calibrated for a longer game" - more likely, you're just Fultoning way less people than they expected you to, or not building up your base enough. With a Fulton-heavy playstyle, the unit level requirements are almost automatic.

Comment: @User2357112 That seems unlikely. I fultoned people using the exact same methods I did in MGSV in MGS:PW (a game which has an almost identical staff progression system with similar scaling) and I had a team that was well over level 60 by the game's proper end, whereas I had about the same level of team that OP did when I beat MGSV.

Comment: @user2357112 My motherbase is fully expanded and fully staffed, and I fulton everyone who has an A+ or better in anything. Actually, since it's the easiest way to hide bodies, I often fulton soldiers regardless of their scores and let motherbase auto-dismiss them later. My progression in R&D was more or less linear and sensible until it stopped abruptly after the final mission.

Comment: @DanC: What about your FOB?

Comment: @LucasLeblanc: Really? Because I'm hitting 70s, no problem.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I beat the entire game and did most of the side ops. Then again, I just realized that I didn't do a lot of the main ops that aren't story-related because I told myself I'd come back to them later. I suppose if the game had as many story-related main ops as PW, then I would be even in R&D team level.

Comment: If it's any consolation, higher sector grades do not really do anything for your gameplay experience. Once you beat the game the only thing left to do is farm out the last of your developments. No cheats exist that anyone knows of, but if they did it would not make for a fun game. Honestly you could probably beat the whole game in a day and say bye bye to $60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a distinction between offline and online gameplay for Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain, as such there are not any cheat codes as changes in the single-player mode would affect multiplayer mode.

Comment: Editors cut down most of this post, but I feel that using the chicken hat is a type of cheat. Check the version history to see what I previously wrote